# Insert datetime in specific format in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I want to store a datetime format in a datetime column.

The format i want to use is: 
14-05-2012 14:08:54

Is the above by the way possible?

The reason for this is that we use Excel sheets to read from the database and using this format will help us a lot in our daily work.

Please advise.

I appreciate your help and answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datetime is datetime, it's not associated with any specific format. If you need to format datetime, use:

```
select convert( char(10), getdate(), 105) +  ' ' + convert( char(8), getdate(), 108)
```

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure if there is an exact output format for the desired result. But I got this to work

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10), getdate(), 105) 
       + ' ' + CONVERT(varchar(8), GETDATE(), 108)
```